# Fedora 9: problem with hibernation and standby

Tags: fedora, standby, hibernate

Whenever I put the the computer to hibernate or standby, black screen appears and it stays forever. How to rectify this? Pressing any key does not wake my system. Finally I do force shutdown and then restart. Even no activity is shown by harddisk.
I have dual boot Fedora/Vista sony vaio.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of this cause, but I HIGHLY recommend you update to at least Fedora 14. Fedora 9 has reached it End of Life a while ago, and no longer has proper support for anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar problem I had on earlier Fedora distributions; hibernation/standby was particularly uncooked in previous releases.

You probably don't want to hear this, but you really should update to Fedora 11, at least, or wait until next week for F12 to be released. Fedora 9 is beyond end-of-life at this point.